# Why does later added owner of chat room not require 1k reputation now?

Tags: bug, chat, gallery

Creating [Gallery chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) require 1k reputation.

I have created chat room named [Enthusiastic Programmers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/13215/enthusiastic-programmers) and RobinHood(who has more than 1k rep) as the owner.

I tried to add another active member Alice(less than 1k rep), and failed to do so. But Alice was added to owner list by RobinHood yesterday.

How is it possible to add room owner with less than 1k rep?

Comment: It's really strange? Can any one please tell reason for downvote?

Comment: Perhaps the [100 rep limit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) for chat room creation plays a role? i.e. you're not allowed to create it, but it's perfectly fine to be invited by others... Don't know for sure though.